# Struggling with C# Events examples

Tags: c#

I'm struggling to implement some Events into some code I'm working on, and the examples provided in the textbook I'm working through don't compile (C# Player's Handbook, 3rd Edition). I've been trying to figure out what I'm not getting about Events/Event Handlers, etc. to no avail.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio (most recent update), and this is the code I'm trying to make work (I didn't write it -- but I think figuring out why it won't work will help me with the other Event problems I'm having).

```
namespace EventsPractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point point = new Point();

            point.PointChanged += HandlePointChanged;
        }

    }
    class Point
    {
        private double x;
        private double y;

        public double X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set
            {
                x = value;
                OnPointChanged();
            }
        }
        public double Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set
            {
                y = value;
                OnPointChanged();
            }

        }

        public event EventHandler PointChanged;

        public void OnPointChanged()
        {
            if (PointChanged != null)
                PointChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public void HandlePointChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // Do something Here
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that on the line

```
point.PointChanged += HandlePointChanged;
```

I am getting the error 'The name HandlePointChanged does not exist in this context.'

Am I missing something obvious? Why won't this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move the `HandlePointChanged()` method into `Program`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have the `HandlePointChanged` in the `Point` class, it needs to be in the consumer class.

Comment: This isn't an event issue.  It's a scope issue.  The method exists on an instance of the `Point` class.  So you could do `point.PointChanged += point.HandlePointChanged;` but it would make more sense to move it out of the class.

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HandlePointChanged is not defined within the class `Program`, which is where you are trying to assign it. It is defined with `Point`.

If you want to handle changes to the Point in a function in the Program class, just move it:

```
namespace EventsPractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point point = new Point();

            point.PointChanged += HandlePointChanged;
        }

        static public void HandlePointChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // Do something Here
        }

    }
    class Point
    {
        private double x;
        private double y;

        public double X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set
            {
                x = value;
                OnPointChanged();
            }
        }
        public double Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set
            {
                y = value;
                OnPointChanged();
            }

        }

        public event EventHandler PointChanged;

        public void OnPointChanged()
        {
            if (PointChanged != null)
                PointChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`HandlePointChanged` is defined in class `Point`. You need to reference it on the right side too, because you are referencing it from class `Program`.

```
point.PointChanged += point.HandlePointChanged;
```

As @juharr mentioned, you need to reference a specific instance of the fuction because it is not static. You could avoid this by making the function static.

Comment: It's not `static` so you have to reference it from an instance.

Comment: @juharr I fixed it ty.

Comment: Wow, that was such an easy fix! Thank you!